# If Brainiac-5 is so smart then why can’t he tell Kara the way out of her conscience

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

In Season 3 Episode 10, "Legion of Super-Heroes", when Kara is trapped in her subconscience, Brainiac-5 is in there too, trying to help her figure out how to get her out. If he is so smart, why couldn’t he just tell Kara a way out?

[image];

Comment: Would you care to share what TV show, episode, movie, book or comic you are asking about? You have tagged this as episode-identification which seems clearly wrong.

Comment: And why is he blue?

Answer (score 1):

Brainiac-5 is smart, not omniscient. He doesn't know what Kara has been through recently (namely trying to deny her humanity) so he wouldn't know her subconscious was trying to tell her to stop trying to be only Kara Zor-El and start being Kara Danvers again.